# How to prove that this definition of the circle defines only one curve, the circle?

Tags: circles, plane-curves

We may start with this definition of the circle:

> The set of all points in the plane that are at equal distance (different from $0$) from some fixed point in that plane is called a circle.

It is *self-evident* that only curve that does the job is the circle.

> How to prove that only the circle does the job?

Added: On second thought, I am not sure that there are no curves that do not have tangent anywhere that would also qualify to satisfy the definition of the circle. Now it is not self-evident any more.

Comment: To me, this is what a circle is. How do _you_ define a circle?

Comment: @Arthur But you are aware that we must show that circle is the only curve that is defined by this definition. What if there are some curves that have tangent nowhere that are also included in this defintion?

Comment: The definition of a circumference is "the set of all and only the points of the plane that have a fixed distance (called *radius*) from a fixed point (called *centre*)".  Your definition doesn't work because for any fixed point $C$ there are infinitely many points at equal distance from $C$ namely all the circumferences with centre $C$ and any radius $r$. Actually the whole plane is made by points which satisfy your definition.

Comment: What is this obsession with a tangent? I don't know any definition of a circle where tangents are so much as mentioned.

Comment: if you want to really mess yourself up think about what a circle is in different metrics.

Comment: "But you are aware that we must show that circle is the only curve that is defined by this definition." No. All curves that fulfill that definition are circles. No matter what they may look like, or what other properties they may have, and what other things some of them might be called. After that one can go and prove that all circles are similar and that they are rotationally symmetric, but that is secondary.

Comment: @Arthur Ok, it would be nice if this definition defines an infinite number of non-similar curves.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your definition of a circle, then a circle is whatever it specifies.  If we give the plane the Manhattan metric, where the distance between two points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ is $|x_1-x_2|+|y_1-y_2|$ circles look like squares that are rotated $45^\circ$ from the axes.  If we give the plane the discrete metric, where the distance between two points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ is $1$ unless the points are identical, the circle of radius $1$ is the whole plane except the center and the circle of any other radius is empty.

What I think you are trying to ask is to prove your stated definition with the usual metric matches some intuitive definition of circle that you have.  If so, we need to understand your intuitive definition to make progress.  Your stated definition is my intuitive definition, so they match easily.

Comment: Yes, with the usual metric, of course.

Comment: We can use this definition of the circle given above (with the usual metric) and then show, if that is the case, that there is only one curve that is defined by that definition, and then we call that curve circle, do you understand now my intentions?

Comment: There is nothing in the definition that mentions a curve.  The circle is the set of all points that satisfy the definition, so it is unique.  When you ask for a curve are you asking that the set of points be one dimensional and parameterized by arc length?  That is something we could try to prove from your definition.  It would exclude my discrete metric example, but not the Manhattan metric example.

Comment: I think that from the above stated defintion (with the requirement of usual-metricity) it would follow that circle must be one-dimensional curve and we could define  curves in the usual way as a continuous images of an interval.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have a point $P(x_0,y_0)$ somewhere in the plane and $f(x,y)$ is the distance of point $(x,y)$ from $(x_0,y_0)$.

Recall that $df=\vec{\nabla} f\cdot d\vec{s}$ where $d\vec{s}$ is an infinitesimal displacement and $\vec{\nabla}f$ is the gradient of $f$. The gradient points in the direction of greatest change of $f$. The direction of zero change lies along a displacement which is perpendicular to the gradient at the given point.

We want $0=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx +\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy$

This happens when $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}=g(x,y)$

A unique solution exists for a given initial point $(x_1,y_1)$ so long as $g$ and $\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}$ are continuous leaving great liberty in $f$, the method of measuring distance.